# Word Search Using 2d arrays in java - getting past the second letter

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, wordsearch

So, I have been tasked with creating a word search program using a 2d array grid.

so far my code can find all 2 letter words in a grid, but go beyond 2 letters in length and the code skips them. I'm currently dead tired at 2am so its probably something obvious im missing, but if it isnt, help me out?

Current searching code:

```
   /**
     * Searches for a word in this LetterGrid using traditional WordSearch
     * rules.
     * 
     * @param word
     *            the word to look for
     */
    public boolean wordSearch(String word)
    {
            // Check each letter in grid
            for (int row = 0; row < this.noOfRows; row++)
            {
                    for (int col = 0; col < this.rowLength; col++)
                    {
                            if (grid[row][col] == word.charAt(0) && word.length() > 1)
                            {
                                    return gridCheck(row, col, word, 1);
                            }
                            else if (grid[row][col] == word.charAt(0))
                            {
                                    return true;
                            }
                    }

            }
            return false;
    }

    public boolean gridCheck(int row, int col, String word, int charToFind)
    {

            if (charToFind == word.length() - 1)
            {
                    return true;
            }
            else if (charToFind < word.length() - 1)
            {
                    // Where is the letter being checked? -contingency check-
                    // if letter being checked is not touching any edge [most likely]
                    if (row > 0 && row < this.noOfRows && col > 0
                                    && col < this.rowLength)
                    {
                            // FOR CODES SEE CHECKPLACES.TXT
                            // A
                            if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // B
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // C
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // D
                            else if (grid[row][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col - 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // E
                            else if (grid[row][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col + 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // F
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // G
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // H
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }

                    }
                    // Letter is touching top left corner
                    if (row == 0 && col == 0)
                    {
                            // E
                            if (grid[row][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col + 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // H
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // G
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                    }
                    // Letter is touching top Right corner
                    if (row == 0 && col == this.rowLength)
                    {
                            // D
                            if (grid[row][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col - 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // F
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // G
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }

                    }
                    // Letter is Touching bottom Left Corner
                    if (row == this.noOfRows && col == 0)
                    {
                            // B
                            if (grid[row - 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // C
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }

                            // E
                            else if (grid[row][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col + 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }

                    }
                    // Letter is touching bottom right corner
                    if (row == this.noOfRows && col == this.rowLength)
                    {
                            // A
                            if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // B
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // D
                            if (grid[row][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col - 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                    }
                    // letter is on top row of grid
                    if (row == 0 && col > 0 && col < this.rowLength)
                    {
                            // D
                            if (grid[row][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col - 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // E
                            else if (grid[row][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col + 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // F
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // G
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // H
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                    }
                    // Letter is on bottom row of grid
                    if (row == this.noOfRows && col > 0 && col < this.rowLength)
                    {
                            // FOR CODES SEE CHECKPLACES.TXT
                            // A
                            if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // B
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // C
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // D
                            else if (grid[row][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col - 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // E
                            else if (grid[row][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col + 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                    }
                    // Letter is on Leftmost column of grid
                    if (col == 0 && row > 0 && row < this.noOfRows)
                    {
                            // B
                            if (grid[row - 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // C
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // E
                            else if (grid[row][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col + 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // G
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // H
                            else if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row + 1, col + 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                    }
                    // Letter is on rightmost column of grid
                    if (col == this.rowLength && row > 0 && row < this.noOfRows)
                    {
                            // A
                            if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col - 1, word,
                                                    word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // B
                            else if (grid[row - 1][col] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row - 1, col, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }
                            // D
                            else if (grid[row][col - 1] == word.charAt(charToFind))
                            {
                                    gridCheck(row, col - 1, word, word.charAt(charToFind + 1));
                            }

                    }
            }

            // If word is not found
            return false;
    }
```

The constructor for the grid object [incase we need it] is as follows -

```
/**
     * Constructs a new LetterGrid Object
     * 
     * @param letterGridFile
     *            the file to use
     */
    public LetterGrid(String letterGridFile)
    {
            try
            {
                    // Init Scanner
                    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(letterGridFile));
                    // Init ArrayList
                    ArrayList<String> nextLine = new ArrayList<String>(10);
                    // Read Data
                    while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
                    {
                            nextLine.add(fileIn.nextLine());
                            noOfRows++;
                    }
                    fileIn.close();

                    rowLength = nextLine.size();
                    grid = new char[noOfRows][rowLength];
                    // Add data to grid
                    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < noOfRows; rowCount++)
                    {

                            grid[rowCount] = (nextLine.get(rowCount).toCharArray());
                    }
            }
            // In case file name is mistyped or nonexistent
            catch (IOException exp)
            {
                    System.out.println("Oops, something went wrong.");
                    System.out.println("--> File Not Found");
            }

    }
```

And finally, the reference i am using to search:

```
Places to check             the X = current letter to check around
Row   Col  Code              A    B    C
-1    -1    A
-1     0    B                D    X    E
-1     1    C
 0    -1    D                F    G    H
 0     1    E
 1    -1    F
 1     0    G
 1     1    H
```

Thankyou to everyone for your help =)

-Apok

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing that I see is that I think your code will count the word "computer" in the following:

```
xxxxxxcxxxxxx
xxxxxoxxxxxxx
xxxxxmxxxxxxx
xxxxxxpuxxxxx
xxxxxretxxxxx
```

Where the X's are arbitrary letters.

I believe you need to implement something that preserves the direction of the search between calls.

For example, if you find the first letter of the word "computer" at a point in the grid and then you find the 'o' to the North-west, then your code should continue to search in the NW direction until it finds a character that is not in the word (or of course if it hits a "wall")

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the trick although you'll need to add extra code to limit the searches within the bounds of the grid (and also this is C# not java, but is pretty much the same)

```
    private Point FindWordInWordSeacrh(String word)
    {
        char[,] grid = new char[10, 10];


        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                int iWOrdCharIndex = 0;
                if (grid[x,y] == word[iWOrdCharIndex])
                {
                    // if the first letter of the word is found
                    iWOrdCharIndex++;

                    // Set the direction vector to continue the search
                    for (int xDir = -1; xDir <= 1; xDir++)
                    {
                        for (int yDir = -1; yDir <= 1; yDir++)
                        {
                            // Diretion vector set so check for remaining letters of word
                            for (int iCharPos = 1; iCharPos < word.Length; iCharPos++)
                            {
                                // Check the next letters of the word along this direction vector
                                if (grid[x+xDir, y+yDir] != word[iCharPos])
                                {
                                    // break loop and chnage direction vector if looking in wrong direction 
                                    break;
                                }
                                else if (iCharPos == word.Length)
                                {
                                    // retun the starting point if word found
                                    return new Point(x, y);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```